Suppose $Z_i$ are i.i.d. $N(0, 1).$ And let $M_n = \max\{Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\}$, show that $P(M_n > t) \leq n(1 - \Phi(t))$
Show that $P(M_n > t) \leq n(1 - \Phi(t))$
My work:
\begin{align}
& P(M_n > t) \leq P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (Z_i > t) \right) \\ \leq {} & \sum_{i=1}^n P(Z_i > t)= n(1 - \Phi(t))
\end{align}
Is the above correct?

A first step is showing $P(M_n > t) =1-\Phi (t)^n$.

@JimB Why do the long way?

@BCLC Nice (and short) answer.  But I assume (or at least hope) you don't believe that there's only one way to do something.  Plus, because the right-hand side of the equation was targeted for the normal distribution, it would seem appropriate that the left-hand side of the equation should also be specific to the normal distribution.

\begin{align}
& P(M_n > t) \leq P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (Z_i > t) \right) \\ \leq {} & \sum_{i=1}^n P(Z_i > t)= n(1 - \Phi(t)).
\end{align}
The above is correct but I would write it like this:
\begin{align}
& P(M_n > t) = P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (Z_i > t) \right) \\ \leq {} & \sum_{i=1}^n P(Z_i > t)= n(1 - \Phi(t)).
\end{align}
When I read the question I spent a few seconds on whether it ought to say $\text{“}{\le}{”}$ or $\text{“}{\ge}{”}.$ It seems clearer if one says that $\left\{ 
M_n>t \right\}$ and $\left\{ \bigcup_{i\,=\,1}^n (Z_i>t) \right\}$ are not just events with the same probability, but are the same event.
